# JQuery - set an image src on button click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, dialog, webmethod

I have a Jquery dialog, which opens up on click of a link.
This click populates the dialog using AJAX. One of the things I need to do is populate it with an image based on the ID coming back from the data returned from the AJAX method.
The images in the site use and ImageHandler to display images like so:

```
~/ImageHandlerDefault.ashx?id=1467
```

This works great, But is there a way I can set an image using the AJAX web method or does it need a postback?

I have attempted to hard code a value but this has not worked:

```
  $('.openwoimage').attr('src', '~/ImageHandlerDefault.ashx?id=1467');
```

I can change the alt etc but the src is nto working.

Does anyone have any advice or a better way of doing it?

thanks

Comment: the `~` prefix is only understood server-side, not client side. You need to resolve the path name for the script (client) to understand where that path lies. (Try looking in to [HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainappvirtualpath.aspx) or `ResolveUrl`)

Comment: Are you able to get that that URL on your own?  Note that this is evaluated client side, not server side.

Comment: very good point you got there, yes it is only recognised by the server, so what i have done is used ResolveURL which works great: 

$('.openwoimage').attr('src', '<%= ResolveUrl("~/ImageHandlerDefault.ashx?id=' + item.ImageId + '") %>');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.openwoimage').attr({
  src: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/ImageHandlerDefault.ashx?id=1467")%>'
});
```

Use `ResolveUrl` to get the "client" version of the path from the server version.

Comment: @Funky: I got to it a few seconds before your comment. ;-)